# ggplot2 plot question in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I created a ggplot2 plot where I struggle with 2 things.

1) How to change the colors?

2) Why is the line missing between items 9 and 10?

```
cent <- rnorm(n=20, mean=5, sd=1)
num <- c(1:20)
groups2 <- c(rep("DSM Symptoms",9),rep("Non-DSM Symptoms",11))
data2 <- data.frame(num, cent, groups2)

ggplot(data2, aes(x=num, y=cent, fill=groups2, colour=groups2)) + 
  geom_line(color='#666666', size=0.7) +
  geom_point() +
  ylab('Strength Centrality') + xlab ('Symptoms') + 
  scale_x_reverse() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1:20)) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank())
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Remove the `fill` in the `aes` if you want a single line. `scale_color_manual(values=c("green","yellow"))` If you want to change the colour of the dots to green and yellow for example.

Comment: To connect the lines, use, `group = 1` within `geom_line` -- `geom_line(color='#666666', size=0.7, group = 1)`. You can use `scale_color_manual` to change the colors, `scale_color_manual(values = c("green", "orange"))`.

Comment: Also, `scale_x_reverse` is getting overridden by `scale_x_continuous`. Use one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example:

```
ggplot(data2, aes(x=num, y=cent, colour=groups2)) + 
   geom_line(color='#666666', size=0.7) +
   geom_point() +
   ylab('Strength Centrality') + xlab ('Symptoms') + 
   scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(20:1)) +
   coord_flip() +
   theme_bw() + scale_color_manual(values=c("cyan","green"))+
   theme(panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank())
```

note the `scale_color_manual(values=c(...))` and the absence of the `fill` parameter in the `aes`thetics section.

[image]

Note that if you want to reverse the ordering, you'd need to do something like 
`scale_x_reverse(breaks=c(1:20))` since the `scale_x_...` options overwrite each other, with only the latest implemented.